# Do all Focusrite Saffire range products use same inputs and outputs?

Tags: audio-interfaces, sound-quality

I'm going to buy my very first sound card, with an aim towards sound quality. I'm looking for both good 2+ inputs and outputs and nicely powered headphone output, since I'm not aiming to buy a headphone amplifier yet.

I'm aiming to go with Focusrite and a bit of info is needed - do all Saffires use same inputs, outputs and chipset or are some superior to others in the terms of sound quality? Cause it's just all about the features and the i/o quality is about the same, I would choose the less-feature one - probably Saffire Pro 24 since I've used it in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on cursory look at the website they seem to share a fairly similar feature set. My guess is that they use extremely similar components and even if they were to use different circuitry they'd still be close enough in specification that they wouldn't make much of a difference in the real world.

http://global.focusrite.com/audio-interface-comparison-chart#Saffire

http://us.focusrite.com/firewire-audio-interfaces/saffire-pro-14/key-features

A good example of this is the difference between 16 and 24 bit audio. Most people can't tell the difference. I think it's likely to be the same here.

Unless you're a real audiophile with decent headphones/monitors you won't be able to tell the difference.

You're best bet is to go into a local store and ask them for a demonstration. DJ/Hifi stores in my area sometimes have this option because the outlay for such devices isn't trivial.

Honestly though, I think this question is more suitably directed at Focusrite support. Their contact details are available here.

http://us.focusrite.com/contact-us